# Get multiple aws account ec2 inventory using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have written the python boto3 code to take the ec2 inventory in AWS and in that same code, I am modifying to take multiple AWS accounts ec2 inventory list into csv but in that I am getting the ec2 output details only for last value. someone help me with the below script to generate multiple AWS ec2 inventory to csv.

```
import boto3
import csv
profiles = ['dev','stag']
for name in profiles:
    aws_mag_con=boto3.session.Session(profile_name=name)
ec2_con_re=aws_mag_con.resource(service_name="ec2",region_name="ap-southeast-1")
cnt=1
csv_ob=open("inventory_info.csv","w",newline='')
csv_w=csv.writer(csv_ob)
csv_w.writerow(["S_NO","Instance_Id",'Instance_Type','Architecture','LaunchTime','Privat_Ip'])

for each in ec2_con_re.instances.all():
    print(cnt,each,each.instance_id,each.instance_type,each.architecture,each.launch_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),each.private_ip_address) 
    csv_w.writerow([cnt,each.instance_id,each.instance_type,each.architecture,each.launch_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),each.private_ip_address])


    cnt+=1
csv_ob.close()
```

above script I am getting the output of stag **aws** account only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your **indentation** is incorrect. The loop only accounts for the first line and everything else will be executed for the last element of `profiles` (when the for loop finishes). It should be:

```
import boto3
import csv
profiles = ['dev','stag']
for name in profiles:
    aws_mag_con=boto3.session.Session(profile_name=name)
    ec2_con_re=aws_mag_con.resource(service_name="ec2",region_name="ap-southeast-1")
    cnt=1
    csv_ob=open("inventory_info.csv","w",newline='')
    csv_w=csv.writer(csv_ob)
    csv_w.writerow(["S_NO","Instance_Id",'Instance_Type','Architecture','LaunchTime','Privat_Ip'])

    for each in ec2_con_re.instances.all():
        print(cnt,each,each.instance_id,each.instance_type,each.architecture,each.launch_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),each.private_ip_address) 
        csv_w.writerow([cnt,each.instance_id,each.instance_type,each.architecture,each.launch_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),each.private_ip_address])


        cnt+=1
    csv_ob.close()
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, Yes its working now, I have corrected the loop which you mentioned above and get the all account ec2 details but in CSV still I am getting only for the stage account ec2 details, dev details not showing. Thanks you!